# How to change elements positioning in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios5, ios4

I am trying to create this simple design [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmYW2.jpg)

The problem is i am not sure how to move the photo to the left when in landscape mode. i have tried putting it into a stack view, but rather than moving the picture to the left when in landscape the whole thing becomes clustered.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your design with size classes maybe. You can check it out here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html

Comment: Dude your a monster!! thank you very much. i have spent the entire day looking for this.